# Deploy Spring Boot (with JSP) to Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: spring, jsp, tomcat, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am attempting to deploy my Spring Boot project to Amazon Elastic Beanstalk.  I have tested and have no issue if I use the default Thymeleaf configuration, but when I switch to JSP based setup I get 404's as it cannot find the JSP's (located in src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp)

I have attempted to deploy the sample (spring-boot-sample-tomcat-jsp) and find that this as well gives me a 404 when I run the provided test.

Here is how I have typically been configuring my Spring Boot Projects to allow for the use of JSP's.

1. Add Jasper and JSTL to pom.xml

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
       <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
       <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Override default view resolver configuration

   ```
   @Configuration
   @EnableWebMvc
   public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
   {

       @Bean
       public ViewResolver getViewResolver(){
           InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
           resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
           resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

           return resolver;
       }

       @Override
       public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer){
           configurer.enable();
       }
   }
   ```
3. Create folder for JSP's (src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp)

Now this method works without issue until I deploy to Elastic Beanstalk where I find that no matter if I create a jar and use Java (in Elastic Beanstalk) or create a war and use Tomcat (in eb) I get a 404 when any controller tries to return a view in the WEB-INF/jsp folder.

Is the above method for switching to JSP's not recommended?  Is there a better way to configure Spring Boot to use Tomcat/Jasper/JSP's?

I have attempted the method provided in the Spring Boot Samples on github [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/v1.5.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-tomcat-jsp)

**But what's interesting is if I run the provided test i get the same 404.**

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  If there is a better way to deploy a Spring Boot project that utilizes JSP's I'd be happy to switch  over, but currently I seem to have configured myself into a corner.

Thx!

Comment: JSPs in jars aren't supported so that part of the problem is to be expected. What test are you referring to when you said "if I run the provided test i get the same 404" and how are you running it?

Comment: I was referring to the supplied test (SampleWebJspApplicationTests) in the spring-boot-sample-tomcat-jsp project provided by the spring-boot project on github.  https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.5.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-tomcat-jsp/src/test/java/sample/tomcat/jsp/SampleWebJspApplicationTests.java

Comment: regarding the JSP/jars comment.  I find the same issue when i switch to a WAR and deploy to eb.

Comment: That test passes for me in my IDE, on the command line, and as part of CI. It sounds to me like your problem might be specific to your environment.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson trying to find the difference here.  I am running my test from IntelliJ as well as my application.  The only difference between my code an the github project is that i removed "<scope>provided</scope>" from the pom.xml for tomcat and jasper dependencies.  I don't understand what's different between our environments.

Comment: when i run the full project, i get all the JSON responses but it will not resolve the path to the JSP's.  for example in the sample project "/fail" returns successfully but just a "/" gives a 404 with the following:       There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
/WEB-INF/jsp/welcome.jsp

Comment: I'm hoping i can get some insight on the differences between the method i provided (overriding the ViewResolver) and the method in the sample(setting application.properties) for utilizing JSP with Spring Boot.   Or just pointers as to how to dig into this deeper within Spring Boot.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering as a novice developer in Springboot development. And, I am just playing around with AWS EB and SpringBoot app deployment.

Here are my findings,

1. WebMvcConfigurerAdapter is deprecated
2. SpringBoot app works seamlessly on AWS EB only when we extend application/main class with SpringBootServletInitializer
3. I tried a sample HelloWorld application extending WebMvcConfigurerAdapter, which worked seamlessly on localhost and failed miserable on AWS EB.
4. I switched the application class extending from WebMvcConfigurerAdapter to SpringBootServletInitializer, this worked on both localhost as well as AWS EB.

The example I tried is inspired from here: https://github.com/in28minutes/deploy-spring-boot-aws-eb/tree/master/03-spring-boot-web-application-h2

Here is the application class that I changed from extending SpringBootServletInitializer to WebMvcConfigurerAdapter, which didn't work and gave me 404.
https://github.com/in28minutes/deploy-spring-boot-aws-eb/blob/master/03-spring-boot-web-application-h2/src/main/java/com/in28minutes/springboot/web/SpringBootFirstWebApplication.java

Hopefully this helps ...!

Still finding out a reason about why we receive 404 when we extend Application class with WebMvcConfigurerAdapter. I Will update this same answer, once I find a reason.

Thank you...!

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar problem. I was able to get response for simple string but could not access JSP pages.
I resolved this by creating an environment > selecting tomcat as platform instead of java and deploying my war file there.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34643133)